# Cartesian equation of $ \vec{r}(t)=\left(e^{\omega t}(\cos(\omega t)+\sin(\omega t)),2\omega e^{\omega t} \cos(\omega t)\right) $

Tags: calculus, geometry, parametric

I have this parametric equation:
$$
\vec{r}(t)=\left(e^{\omega t}(\cos(\omega t)+\sin(\omega t)),2\omega e^{\omega t} \cos(\omega t)\right)
$$
and I have to obtain the Cartesian equation. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done but only implicitly and the expression is pretty ugly...
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{y}{2\omega} &= e^{\omega t}\cos(\omega t)\\
x - \frac{y}{2\omega} &= e^{\omega t}\sin(\omega t)\\
\end{cases}
\implies
\begin{cases}
e^{\omega t} &= \sqrt{\left(\frac{y}{2\omega}\right)^2 + \left(x - \frac{y}{2\omega}\right)^2}\\
\tan(\omega t) &= \frac{2\omega x}{y} - 1
\end{cases}\\
\implies
\frac{2\omega x}{y} = 1 + \tan\left\{\frac12\log\left[\left(\frac{y}{2\omega}\right)^2 + \left(x - \frac{y}{2\omega}\right)^2\right]\right\}
$$
**Update**

As pointed out by B.S., above implicit representation is plagued with artifact. This is
caused by the use of ratio like $\frac{x}{y}$ which killed the information about the signs
and by the discontinuity of the $\tan$ function. A more well behaved implicit representation is given by:

$$R(x,y) - \frac{y}{2\omega}\cos\log R(x,y)  - \left(x - \frac{y}{2\omega}\right)\sin\log R(x,y) = 0$$
where $\quad\displaystyle R(x,y) = \sqrt{\left(\frac{y}{2\omega}\right)^2 + \left(x - \frac{y}{2\omega}\right)^2}$.

Up to what I have checked, this reproduce the same curve as the parametric parametrization.

Please note that even this implicit representation is correct, it is always non-negative and
only becomes 0 on the curve. The implicit plot of some CAS (e.g Maxima) cannot handle this type of representation properly without some tweaking. If you want to plot this out for comparison and don't mind a reflected copy of the curve. You can use following implicit representation instead:

$$\frac{y}{2\omega}\sin\log R(x,y) - \left(x - \frac{y}{2\omega}\right)\cos\log R(x,y) = 0$$

Comment: I did the same and I think we have this solution only, however its plot is not coincide with above $r(t)$. +1

Comment: @B.S. You are right, this implicit representation seems to pick up an extra oval and a reflection of the actual curve. The reflection part is sort of expected. The oval looks like an artifact, let me think.

Comment: @B.S. There are other implicit representations without that many of artifacts. However, all of them are still pretty ugly.

Comment: Dear friend, I see and confirm that they are so ugly. When I saw its plot, I became reluctant to complete the solution. But you did it complete and made us glad of typing such these messy equations. Thanks for letting me see your way again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Let $x=e^{\omega t}(\cos(\omega t)+\sin(\omega t))$ and $y=2\omega e^{\omega t} \cos(\omega t)$ and try to eliminate $t$

Comment: But this is his question of how can we eliminate $t$. :-)

Comment: @B.S., Can we divide to get $t$ as $\arctan$ containing $x,y$?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: I am thinking....${}{}$:-(